# What strict type does styled component need?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

So this is my Hoc
I have created this so I can keep my styling in a separate file. Only problem is, the ReactElement is failing for styled component. I'm not sure what type to replace this with?

```js
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

type TGetStyled = (props: { Component: ReactElement; pad: string }) => ReactElement;

const GetStyled: TGetStyled = ({ Component, pad }) => styled(Component)`
  a {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: ${pad};
    &:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
  }
`;
export default GetStyled;
```

What type should I put in place of 'ReactElement'?

Error:

```
Type '({ Component, pad }: { Component: ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>; pad: string; }) => StyledComponent<...>' is not assignable to type 'TGetStyled'.
  Type 'String & StyledComponentBase<any, any, any, any> & NonReactStatics<any, {}>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>': type, props, key

No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(component: AnyStyledComponent): ThemedStyledFunction<any, any, any, any>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyStyledComponent'.
      Type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>' is not assignable to type 'StyledComponent<any, any, any, never>'.
        Type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(component: "symbol" | "object" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "bdi" | "bdo" | "big" | "blockquote" | "body" | "br" | "button" | "canvas" | ... 157 more ... | FunctionComponent<...>): ThemedStyledFunction<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>' is not assignable to parameter of type '"symbol" | "object" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "bdi" | "bdo" | "big" | "blockquote" | "body" | "br" | "button" | "canvas" | ... 157 more ... | FunctionComponent<...>'.
      Type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<any>'.
        Type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>' provides no match for the signature '(props: any, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a better solution than my previous answer, as the previous answer can lead to memory leak as responded to in styled-components

## LinkStyle.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled, { StyledComponent } from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { TStyles } from './Theme';

const StyleMe: TStyles = ({ theme: { blue1, blue2 } }) => `
  color: ${blue1};
  display: inline-block;
  &:hover {
    color: ${blue2};
  }
`;

const StyleComponent = (): StyledComponent<typeof Link, {}> =>
  styled(Link)`
    ${StyleMe}
  `;

export default StyleComponent;
```

## Usecase.tsx

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { withTheme } from 'styled-components';

import { TTheme } from './Theme';
import LinkStyle from './LinkStyle';

const LinkStyled = LinkStyle();

const MyComponent: FC<{ theme: TTheme }> = () => (
  <nav>
    <LinkStyled to="/somepath">some link</LinkStyled>
  </nav>
);

export default withTheme(MyComponent);
```

## Theme.tsx

```js
const theme = {
  blue1: '#22f',
  blue2: '#77f'
};

export type TTheme = typeof theme;
```

This also negates the need for any removal of jest warnings, which in itself was a bit hacky anway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the answer by scraping information on hocs, and looking at the @types/styled-components/index.d.ts

## Wrapper for components

#### Style.tsx

- (Ensure saved as .tsx and not .ts)

```js
import { ComponentType } from 'react';
import styled, { StyledComponent } from 'styled-components';

// Note: this is to allow dynamic population of props
// Must be of string type. Could be something else but in this example just set as string
type TKeyString = {
  [index: string]: string;
};

const Style = <P extends {}>(
  Comp: ComponentType<P>,
  props: TKeyString
): StyledComponent<ComponentType<P>, {}> => styled(Comp)`
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: ${props.pad10} ${props.pad10};
  margin: 0 0 0 ${props.pad10};
  background: ${props.grey1};
  border: 1px solid ${props.grey2};
  color: ${props.link};
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  &:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: ${props.linkHighlight};
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
`;

export default Style;
```

#### Usecase.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Style from './Style';


const LinkStyled = StyleLink(Link, { 
  pad10: '10px',
  pad20: '20px',
  grey1: '#fefefe',
  grey2: '#363636',
  link: '#44f',
  linkHighlight: '#88f'
});

const MyComponent = () => (
<LinkStyled to={'/'}>homepage</LinkStyled>
)
export default MyComponent;
```

## Wrapper for elements (basic approach):

#### Style.tsx

```
const StyleNav = (props: TTheme): StyledComponent<'nav', {}> => styled.nav`
  background: ${props.grey1};
  display: block;
`;
```

## How to remove jest warnings?

#### finding console.warn message location:

- node_modules\styled-components\dist\styled-component.browser.cjs.js

```js
function checkDynamicCreation(displayName, componentId) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    var parsedIdString = componentId ? " with the id of \"" + componentId + "\"" : '';
    var message = "The component " + displayName + parsedIdString + " has been created dynamically.\n" + 'You may see this warning because you\'ve called styled inside another component.\n' + 'To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.';
}
}
```

#### jest.config.js

```js
{
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest/removeStyledWarn.js']
}
```

#### removeStyleWarn.js

```
const strStyledComponentWarning = 'To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside';

const originalWarn = global.console.warn.bind(global.console.warn);
jest.spyOn(global.console, 'warn').mockImplementation(msg => {
  if (!msg.includes(strStyledComponentWarning)) {
    originalWarn(msg);
  }
});
```