# A typescript type that allows any html attribute

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I', trying to create a react component which emulates a native html element.

## Problem 1:

Allowing a valid html attribute

Example:

```js
type TAtt = {
  [key: string]: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>;
};

const NavAnyValidAttribute: React.FC<TAtt> = props => {
  const { children, ...therest } = props;
  return <nav {...therest}>{children}</nav>;
};

<NavAnyValidAttribute className="x">some children</NavAnyValidAttribute>;
```

## Error

> Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'HTMLAttributes'.(2559)
> input.tsx(135, 3): The expected type comes from this index signature.

## Problem 2:

```js
type TProps = TAtt & {
  TagName: string; //keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements - also doesn't work!;
}

const Tag: React.FC<TProps> = ({ TagName, children, ...props }) =>
  React.createElement(TagName, props, children);

const Nav = <Tag {...{ TagName: 'nav' }} />;
```

> Error: Type '{ TagName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TAtt'.
> Property 'TagName' is incompatible with index signature.
> Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'HTMLAttributes'.ts(2322)

Any help appreciated.
thanks

Comment: "I'm trying to create a React component which emulates a native HTML element." - why?

Comment: so i can pass it to this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482262/what-strict-type-does-styled-component-need

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have created a solution.

I'm sure there is a better way of doing it but in order to keep this strict, and allow passing this component to another unknown component handler I had to ensure I returned the Component<any>.

I also had to ensure I had a strict TagName: React.ElementType. Or "keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements". Not sure which is more appropriate. But the same has to be used for both methods as below.

I also had to return the method GetTagAsComp as a member of the same component TagAsComp.

If anyone has a tidier approach feel free to add.

```js
import React from 'react';

type TElem = React.ElementType; // OR keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;

// Might have to extend this for specific element attributes - see
// - https://www.saltycrane.com/cheat-sheets/typescript/react/latest/
type TAtt = React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>;

type TCreateElement = {
  TagName: TElem;
  props: TAtt;
};

const CreateElement: React.FC<TCreateElement> = ({ TagName, props, children }) =>
  React.createElement(TagName, props, children);

// technically this is a hoc, so would use prefix - with
// but it doesnt name well
// This existing name: TagAsComp is better describing what it is in shorthand - Tag as a component.
const TagAsComp = (TagName: TElem): React.ComponentType<any> => {
  const GetTagAsComp: React.FC<TAtt> = props => {
    const { children } = props;
    return <CreateElement {...{ TagName, props, children }} />;
  };
  return GetTagAsComp;
};

export default TagAsComp;

// Usecase:
// const Tag = TagAsComp('div')
// <Tag onClick={doThing} className="hello" data-x="extra"> Some children </Tag>
```

For my usecase I wanted to pass it to styled components like this:
See my other post:

- [What strict type does styled component need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482262/what-strict-type-does-styled-component-need)

```js
  const Nav = Style(TagAsComp('div'), theme);
```

## Going forward for styled components on an element:

The above solution was not needed, though it answer my original question and maybe beneficial for other use cases.

I would prefer this now as its more elegant:

```
const StyleNav = (props: TTheme): StyledComponent<'nav', {}> => styled.nav`
  background: ${props.grey1};
  display: block;
`;
```